# Specifying variant specific external dependencies in Java software model

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying out the incubating new software model for building my Java project by going thought the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_software.html

What I would like to do is have different external dependencies for different targetPlatforms. Something like,

```
model {
    components {
        main(JvmLibrarySpec) {
            targetPlatform 'java7'
            targetPlatform 'java8'
            binaries.java7Jar {
                dependencies {
                    compile group: 'xyz', name: 'dep7', version: '1.0'
                }
            }
            binaries.java8Jar {
                dependencies {
                    compile group: 'xyz', name: 'dep8', version: '1.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it's failing with the following error,

> No signature of method: org.gradle.jvm.JarBinarySpec.dependencies() is
>   applicable for argument types: ...

Any idea how to do this? Is it even possible?
Note: I don't want to declare another project as a dependency, I want to download the dependency from an existing repository.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to wrap your dependencies block into a java closure thats how it is shown in the docs